# Which type of java project ? Which IDE to import?

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, vnc

I have downloaded a java project named "Enhanced Vnc Thumbnail Viewer".

Source : http://sourceforge.net/projects/evnctv/reviews?source=navbar

But I dont know which IDE and how to import this project to customize it. Please tell me how to indentify which type of any java project and how to import ?

[image]

Here is project.xml:

[image]

Comment: Look at the `project.xml`, which clearly says `netbeans`: arggg, I think then it be a [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/) project.

Comment: I saw it. But still dont know how to import. If use NetBean : Open Project , I cant choose project folder, NetBean cant understand it as a Project, it think it just a folder

Answer (score 0):

The project was created in NetBeans (the clue is in the project.xml), however you can use any Java IDE you want.

Comment: Pleas tell me how to import ? In Eclise and Java, I chosen File > Import but IDE cant understand project folder, so I cant import it.

Answer (score 0):

Your project.xml states that it's netbeans. You can import the project into any Java IDE though or just use a text editor and the command prompt to compile it. The given project you have downloaded uses ant for build management, which will make compiling from the command line easier if you go with that route.  For instructions on importing into eclipse see: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-importproject.htm. For netbeans seehttps://netbeans.org/kb/73/java/project-setup.html?print=yes .

Comment: Please tell me more. I used Eclipse, File > Import > General > Existing Projects into Workspace > Select root directory and chosen to folder above, but Eclipse said "No projects are found to import"

Comment: For a project that was not already an eclipse project you need to create a project and then import the existing files.  Here are a couple links for how you can do this:http://choorucode.com/2014/02/18/how-to-create-eclipse-project-from-existing-source/   http://techforpassion.blogspot.com/2013/03/Eclipse-create-project-from-existing-source.html?m=1

Comment: @JeremyFarrell Eclipse project link is: http://codeyarns.com/2014/02/18/how-to-create-eclipse-project-from-existing-source/

Answer (score 0):

Your project seems to be ant (build.xml). You could use any IDE or even a notepad.
You could import the project as 'Ant Project' using your favorite IDE (say eclipse)
Ofcourse, as folks above suggested NetBeans might work best here...

Comment: Please tell me more how to import as Ant Project ? Eclipse said `No projects are found to import` and NetBean doesnt understand it like a project